# Firebase loading old data into table view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I noticed that my table view of companies displays old data instead of the data that's currently in the database when I pull up firebase on my browser. Why? How do I fix this?

```
databaseHandle = databaseRef?.child("companies").observe(.value, with: 

{ (snapshot) in
            for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                //Load company data into company object
                let company = Company()
                company.name = item.childSnapshot(forPath: Property.name.rawValue).value as! String           
                let positions = item.childSnapshot(forPath: Property.jobtypes.rawValue).value as! String
                company.positions = positions.components(separatedBy: ", ")
                
                //Get company image
                let id = item.childSnapshot(forPath: Property.id.rawValue).value as! String
                let imageName = id + ".png"
                let imageRef = self.storageRef?.child(imageName)
                imageRef?.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print((error as Error).localizedDescription)
                    } else if let data = data {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            company.image = UIImage(data: data)
                            self.companyTableView.reloadData()                        }
                    }
                }
                self.informationStateController?.addCompany(company)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have set persistenceEnabled = true, the snapshot returned by the Firebase API is from the local data cache.  That data is loaded into your Company objects.

While that is happening, a call is made to the Firebase server, with a value observer being set on the companies node of your project.  That value observer triggers the server to send a fresh snapshot to your app.  Handling that second snapshot appears to be the issue.

The way your completion handler is structured, the second snapshot does not update the existing Company objects.  Instead, the completion handler unpacks the second snapshot into a new set of Company objects, with each object being appended to the DOM by the call to informationStateController.addCompany(company).

You should modify your completion handler so that it is able to correlate snapshot data with existing Company objects in your DOM and/or is able to determine whether snapshot data corresponds to new Company objects that are not already in your DOM.  In the former case, it should update the existing Company object, and in the latter case, it should create a new Company object.

I'm not sure of best practices, but in my experience, it is helpful to set a value observer on nodes that correspond to objects in the DOM.  In your case, that would mean setting the observer on each company node rather than on the collective companies node.  In that fashion, it is easier to identify and handle data changes.  To make that work, you may need to start with a value observer on the companies node to compile a full set of Company objects, then remove the value observer from that node, and replace it with a value observer on each company node.

EDIT:

So, to put more shape to my original suggestion:

Start with your original code (modified slightly), and build your DOM array of Company objects.  The mods to the original code would be:

(1) to check whether a Company object already exists in the array before appending a new one, and

(2) as each Company is added to the DOM array, call observe .event on the node for each Company; with the completion handler for each node calling to a method on the corresponding Company object so that it can update itself with the delivered snapshot.

At the same time, setup your .childAdded observer on the companies node.  The completion handler for that observer would be basically the same as your original code (as modified).

THEN, once execution has reached a point that you can know or be confident that you've captured all then-existing companies, remove the original observe .event from the companies node.

Comment: Hi would you be able to provide code for your answer? I'm not sure how to "start with a value observer on the companies node to compile a full set of Company objects, then remove the value observer from that node, and replace it with a value observer on each company node." Within my `.observe(.value` handle, should I do `item.observe(.childAdded` and then assign all the properties to each company object under `.childAdded` handle?

Comment: You could go the .childAdded route, as you suggest.  However, that would not address changes to the data for a specific company.  Does the company data change from time to time, or are the changes limited to adding new companies?

Comment: for the most part, the data inside the company object changes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem of old data still being shown. In your appDelegate if you have `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` then change whichever vc that is showing the old data with the observer from `observeSingleEvent(of: .value, ...)` to `.observe( .childAdded, ...)` and it should resolve the issue. Using `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` Firebase will pull data from your phone via `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` before making the dip to the database to get the fresh info.

I followed this link: [Firebase erroneously shows deleted data / Swift 3 / Xcode 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185393/firebase-erroneously-shows-deleted-data-swift-3-xcode-8-2)